# Можно ли в WebView отображать страницы при помощи Content Provider'a

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! 
Сейчас загрузка страницы происходит так:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/MyPage.htm")
```

а можно ли сделать, что бы загрузка происходила через Content Provider?
Например так:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("content://com.example/MyPage.htm")
```

Но так не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос сложный...

В WebView есть такая функция: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, если она возвращает `true`, то тогда управление будет передано оси с запросом на обработку данного урла системой. Тогда по идее должен быть вызван `ActivityManager`, который по `mime` типу ресурса выдаст список приложений (имеющих соответствующий `ContentProvider`) откуда можно будет выбрать нужный.

В общем надо пробовать.